# What's the equivalent of this Javascript regexp in PHP?

Tags: php, javascript, html, regex, forms

I have this js regexp which I need in PHP code now instead:

```
var alphaExp = /^[a-zA-ZåäöÅÄÖ\s\-]+$/;
if (!fld.value.match(alphaExp)) {
  //ERROR OUTPUT HERE
}
```

Whats the equivalent to this in PHP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$string = "åäöÅÄÖ";
$alphaExp = "/^[a-zA-ZåäöÅÄÖ\s\-]+$/";
if(!preg_match($alphaExp, $string)) {
  //ERROR OUTPUT HERE
  echo "ERROR";
}
```

Comment: You forgot the quote the contents of `$alphaExp`.